# Como medir a associação entre variáveis ​ordinais e nominais?

Tags: static, spss

Quero medir a associação entre gênero e o número de atribuição de cada pontuação em um questionário. Porém, eu tenho uma tabela de referência 2x6 com números inferiores a 5 em mais de uma casela (mais de 20% das caselas).

Procurando alguma solução encontrei o teste de "Goodman e Kruskal's gama", mas não tenho certeza se esta é a melhor escolha. Minha dúvida está na suposição de que este teste é usado para medir a associação entre variáveis ​​ordinais, e eu tenho uma variável nominal no caso o gênero é nominal.

Eu ficaria feliz se alguém pudesse me dar uma pequena ajuda sobre isso.

Comment: Welcome to SOPT, here being the Portuguese version of StackOverflow, questions should be in Portuguese. Would have [edit] your question?

Comment: obrigada pela ajuda.. eu não sabia que existia uma versão em português...